# Reprojecting British National Grid (27700) coords to Mercator (3857) using Proj4j

Tags: coordinate-system, java, proj4js

On epsg.io https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=3857&x=327420.9886680&y=690284.5471100 the BNG easting/northing coodinates 327420.988668 690284.547110 reproject correctly to -352695.04 7578309.23. If I attempt to reproject the same coordinates using proj4j (0.1.0) with the following code:

```
Double easting = 327420.988668;
Double northing = 690284.54711;
CoordinateReferenceSystem BNG = crsFactory.createFromParameters("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");
CoordinateReferenceSystem MERCATOR = crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:3857");
CoordinateTransform trans = ctFactory.createTransform(BNG, MERCATOR);
ProjCoordinate in = new ProjCoordinate(easting, northing);
ProjCoordinate out = new ProjCoordinate();
trans.transform(in, out);
log.info(String.format("%s : %s", out.x, out.y));
```

I get -352695.04030562507 : 7542788.088927755.  The Y coord is around 30 miles south of the correct position.  If I use version 1.0.0 of proj4j, I get -352535.43434034986 : 7578324.217405743, which is much closer but still around 200 meters out.

Incidently if I reproject first to EPSG:4326 then to EPSG:3857, I get the correct result.

Comment: Where do you take those towgs84 parameters? GDAL 3.0 seems to think that there is no need for them `gdalsrsinfo epsg:27700
PROJ.4 : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs`.

Comment: I would check the proj definition of 3857. 30 miles sounds like ellipsoidal Mercator, not the spherical Mercator equations that should be used.

Comment: I got the paramaters from the proj4j definition here: https://epsg.io/27700.  Removing them does not correct the projection.

Comment: did you find the way to convert the coordinates?

Comment: No I didn't ...